# Openstack SDK to resize the instance

Tags: sdk, openstack, openstacksdk

I have a requirement to read the input YAML file and resize the servers with the specified configuration like(VCPU, Disk,memory..). Note that the server name is already exist in the environment. I have automated this using python code using the cli command. Reference link for command
https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/resize.html

But the requirement is to implement this via SDK. Please let me know how to implement this logic via python code by invoking openstack SDK?

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04

Input Yaml:
Servername1: test1
VCPU: 2
Disk: 4000
Memory: 200

Servername2: test2
VCPU: 1
Disk: 1000
Memory: 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SDK API documentation, the `Compute` class ([doc](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/compute.html)) has methods called `resize_server`, `confirm_resize_server` and `revert_resize_server`.

> Please let me know how to implement this logic via python code by invoking openstack SDK?

The sequence would be:

1. Read your yaml file.
2. Find the existing server that you want to resize.
3. Lookup flavor<sup>1</sup> with the specs that you need (VCPUs, disk, memory, etc).
4. Check that the server doesn't have that flavor already.
5. Resize the server
6. Check server is working correctly.  How you do that will depend on the context.  But if you skip this step and "confirm" anyway there is a risk that you will lose the existing server.
7. Either confirm resize or revert resize

For more information how to obtain and make calls on the `Compute` object, please see ["Using OpenStack Compute"](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/guides/compute.html).

---

<sup>1 - You could also synthesize flavors on the fly, but that is liable to give you a flavor management issue in the long term.</sup>